# How do I reset stdin in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, stdin

I'm trying to write a urlview clone in Haskell. The program reads a message (piped via STDIN), extracts all URLs and asks the user to select one of them.

After reading the message, STDIN obviously reaches EOF. In Python, I reset STDIN like this

```
message = sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')
selected_index = raw_input('Which URL to open? ')
```

How would I achieve the same in Haskell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to "re-assign" the built-in `stdin` in Haskell, but you can otherwise open a new handle to `/dev/tty`. A direct translation of your Python code would be something like

```
import System.IO

main = do
    message <- getContents
    tty <- openFile "/dev/tty" ReadMode
    putStr "Which URL to open? "
    url <- hGetLine tty
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

You cannot change the `stdin` handle in Haskell. In Python, the `sys.stdin` variable only *points* to a handle, so when you replace it with a new file handle, the old `stdin` *handle* still remains, but the `sys.stdin` *variable* now contains the file handle.

Since the [`System.IO.stdin`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO.html#v:stdin) handle is immutable in Haskell (as are so many other variables, or should I say values), you cannot do the same thing in Haskell.

What you can do is to open the `/dev/tty` file with a *new handle*, and use that handle to read from the terminal. You can use all of the same operations on any handle as you can on `stdin`. Simply import [`System.IO`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO.html), and every time you would otherwise use `foo ...` to get some input, instead use `hFoo handle ...`. For instance, to read a line from the terminal, use this code:

```
import System.IO

-- ...
newstdin <- openFile "/dev/tty" ReadMode
-- Instead of normal getLine; just prepend "h" and pass the handle
line <- hGetLine newstdin
```

Don't forget to close your new handle with a call to `hClose`!